# Dibujado de ruta con Polylines

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Tengo el siguiente problema a la hora de dibujar una ruta con Polylines.
(Cabe decir que los puntos Lat y Lng los recupero de un archivo JSON local)

Como verán en el mapa, la ruta de una linea de tranporte se dibuja sin problemas, pero aparece una linea recta que une el inicio con el final y eso no deberia de estar ahi, y la verdad, eso me molesta mucho. He intentando de varias formas resolver este problema pero la verdad todsas sin exito. De verdad, agradeceria su ayuda para resolver este problema que tengo. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aqui esta todo el codigo que empleo**

```
class LineaRuta extends StatefulWidget {
  const LineaRuta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LineaRutaState createState() => _LineaRutaState();
}

class _LineaRutaState extends State<LineaRuta> {

  GoogleMapController? controller;
  
  Set<Marker> markers ={};
  Set<Polyline> polyline = Set<Polyline>();
  List<LatLng> latlng = [];
  List<Marker> _markers = [];

  static final CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-17.4139766, -66.1653224),
    zoom: 14,
  );
  
  final Set<Polyline> _polyline = {};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final todo = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Linea;
    
    var cont=0;
    //List<double> puntos = <double>[];
    for (var e in todo.ruta[0].puntos) { 
      latlng.add(new LatLng(e.lat, e.lng));

      if(cont==0){
        _markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('origin'),
            position: LatLng(e.lat, e.lng)
          )
        );
      }
      else if (cont == todo.ruta[0].puntos.length-1) {
        _markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('destination'),
            position: LatLng(e.lat, e.lng)
          )
        );
      }
      cont++;
    }
    print(latlng);
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              size: 28,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
          polylines: _polyline,
          onMapCreated: _OnMapCreated,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _OnMapCreated(GoogleMapController mapController) {

    setState(() {
      controller = mapController;

      _polyline.add(Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId('linea'),
        visible: true,
        points: latlng,
        width: 3,
        color: Colors.red,
      ));
    });
  }

}
```

Recalco que no estoy usando Direction API de Google.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Esa línea recta que te muestra es por que en tu lista de latlng que rellenas en tu ciclo for viene incluida las coordenadas de tu punto "A" y tu punto "B". Me explicó, como funciona el dibujado de rutas con polyline es que se dibuja una línea en el mapa por cada coordenada que le envíes entonces como envías una lista muy grande de coordenadas, cada una muy cerca de otra, esto quiere decir que tu mapa se dibujan muchos puntos y ¿que son muchos puntos si cada uno esta cerca del otro? eso una línea. Dicho lo anterior la solución es que de tu lista de latlng solo debes de eliminar aquellas coordenadas que están muy separadas, que serían las de tu punto "A" a "B", que posiblemente se encuentren al inicio o final de tu lista de latlng.